# backbone collection fetch subtitute $.ajax

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to understanding backbone code. I read this
http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/

then I plan to change this

> ```
>     if (this._index === null){
>         $.ajax({
>             url: 'data/blog.json',
>             dataType: 'json',
>             data: {},
>             success: function(data) {
>                 ws._data = data;
>                 console.log(ws._data);
>                 ws._blogs = new BlogCollection(data.rows);
>                 console.log(ws._blogs);
>                 ws._index = new IndexView({model: ws._blogs}); 
>                 Backbone.history.loadUrl();
>             }
>         });
>         return this;
>     }
>     return this;
> ```

use collection fetch

> ```
>     if (this._index === null){
>         ws._data = new BlogCollection;
>         ws._data.fetch({success: function(data){console.log(data.models[0].attributes);}});
>
>
>         //ws._blogs = new BlogCollection(ws._data.rows);
>         //ws._index = new IndexView({model: ws._blogs});
>         Backbone.history.loadUrl();
>
>     }
> ```

with this collection

> var BlogCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
>       model: Blog,
>       url : 'data/blog.json',
>       parse: function(response){
>              return response;
>           }

when I read the response from collection, it's give same value as using jquery ajax.
but when I use fetch in controller, why I have to access data.models[0].attributes); to get the same data return.

this is my json

> { "page":"1", "total": "5", "records": "25", "rows":
>       [
>           {
>               "title": "Classic Pop",
>               "author": "Michael Jackson Collection",
>               "image": "images/1.jpg",
>               "tags": ["xyz", "abc", "def"],
>               "slug" : "classic-pop",
>               "url": "http://www.localhost/news",
>               "intro": "hello test",
>               "content": "hello test, alfjldsajfldjsflja dljfldasjfa jfljdasfl jfldsjf jljdafl jl"
>           },
>           {
>               "title": "Modern Pop/R&B",
>               "author": "Bruno Mars and Others",
>               "image": "images/54.jpg",
>               "tags": ["test", "test2", "test3"],
>               "slug" : "modern-pop-rb",
>               "url": "http://www.localhost/news",
>               "intro": "hello test 2",
>               "content": "hello test, alfjldsajfldjsflja dljfldasjfa jfljdasfl jfldsjf jljdafl jl"
>           }
>       ] }

how to make fetch works right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When extending your Backbone Collection, *you should define a `parse` function that returns an array of rows that represent the models contained in your collection*.

In your case, it must be an array of data, with each object in the array representing your `Blog` model, so you need to return the `rows` property:

```
var BlogCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: Blog, 
    url : 'data/blog.json', 
    parse: function(response){ 
        return response.rows; 
    }
});
```

Then if your model has a `parse` function, it will get the data for each object contained in the array, in case you need to do anything with the data before the model's attributes are set:

```
var Blog = Backbone.Model.extend({

    //data will contain one of the items returned from the collection's 'parse' function. 
    parse: function(data){
        return data;    
    }
});
```

This will ensure that the Backbone collection will properly create and populate the models represented in the collection with the data.

You will probably want to expose the other metadata (`page, total, records`) on the collection too, perhaps with a property that is also a `Backbone.Model` of page/total/records.